# ‘I gave three people an egg each.’

Tags: adverbs

I want to ask about how focusing adverbs change meanings of nouns or noun phrases.

First off, ‘approximately 99 degrees’ in ‘water boils at approximately 99 degrees’ means ‘100 degrees.’

Likewise, does ‘an egg each’ in ‘I gave three people an egg each’ mean ‘three eggs’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other guiding context, the implied meaning of the word "approximately" is relative to the precision of the number given.

For instance, the number 100 is a round number, so "approximately 100" would usually mean anything from 90 to 110.

But the number 99 is not a round number. It is precise to one integer, so "approximately 99" probably means something like "98.5 to 99.5", and will almost never include 100.

To your second sentence, yes, "an egg each" to three people means three eggs.